# Unable to update services on project members

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

With the patch "projects/:project_id/users/:user_id" endpoint, I'm able to update the industry role on a project member but not the services associated (insight, project management, field management...).

I did some tests (with postman) and I succeded to update "project admin" and "document management" services and that's all.

On the web client when I change manually the industry role, it works well.
So maybe I didn't catch the usefulness of industry roles or maybe it's not possible yet or maybe it's not supposed to work that way, i don't know i'm confused.

May I have a little help?
Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm checking with our engineering team, and will get you back A.S.A.P.